# Should we judge or not?

Tags: contradiction, judgement

Note the apparent diversity of views in the NT about judging others:

**We should not Judge**

- Matt 7:1, 2 - “Do not judge, or you will be judged. 2For with the same judgment you pronounce, you will be judged; and with the measure you use, it will be measured to you.
- Rom 14:4, 13, 22 - Who are you to judge someone else’s servant? To his own master he stands or falls. And he will stand, for the Lord is able to make him stand. ... Therefore let us stop judging one another. Instead, make up your mind not to put any stumbling block or obstacle in your brother’s way. ... Keep your belief about such matters between yourself and God. Blessed is the one who does not condemn himself by what he approves.
- 1 Cor 4:5 - Therefore judge nothing before the appointed time; wait until the Lord comes. He will bring to light what is hidden in darkness and will expose the motives of men’s hearts. At that time each will receive his praise from God.
- Col 2:16 - Therefore let no one judge you by what you eat or drink, or with regard to a feast, a New Moon, or a Sabbath.
- James 4:12 - There is only one Lawgiver and Judge, the One who is able to save and destroy. But who are you to judge your neighbor?

**We should judge**

- Luke 12:57 - And why don’t you judge for yourselves what is right?
- John 7:24 - Stop judging by outward appearances, and start judging justly.”
- Acts 13:46 - And Paul and Barnabas, having spoken boldly, said, "It was necessary for the word of God to be spoken first to you. But since you thrust it away and do not judge yourselves worthy of eternal life, behold, we are turning to the Gentiles.
- 1 Cor 5:12 - What business of mine is it to judge those outside the church? Are you not to judge those inside?
- 1 Cor 6:1-6 - ... Do you not know that we will judge angels? How much more the things of this life! ...
- 1 Cor 11:13 - Judge for yourselves: Is it proper for a woman to pray to God with her head uncovered?

Should we judge others or not?

Comment: Each of these verses have contexts (gramatical and historical) that explain when to judge and when not, and what kind of judgement should we have...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado - that is true - so should we judge or not?

Comment: Sorry, but I’m voting to close this question because it is the epitome of theological synthesis.

Answer (score 4):

Should we judge or not?

That depends on what kind of judging and your heart. There are at least 3 different Greek words for the different concepts of judging.

Luke 6:

> 37 “Do not judge [G2919], and you will not be judged. Do not condemn [G2613], and you will not be condemned. Forgive, and you will be forgiven.

G2919 (judge, κρίνω, krinó) occurs 115 times.
G2613 (condemn, καταδικάζω, katadikazo) occurs 6 times.

Thayer's Greek Lexicon:

> STRONGS NT 2613
> to give judgment against (one), to pronounce guilty; to condemn; in classical Greek (where it differs from κρίνειν in giving prominence to the **formal and official** as distinguished from the **inward and logical judging**

G2613-condemn is a formal and official kind of judging. G2919-judge is an inward and logical kind of judging.

Jesus is telling us: Do not formally pronounce condemnation on someone and do not even judge someone to be guilty by your inward logic. Leave that to God. You can warn people but don't be judgmental.

G2919-judge is ambiguous. There is a sense that as a group, we do judge.
Paul used this sense in 1 Corinthians 6:

> 1 When one of you has a grievance against another, does he dare go to **law before the unrighteous** instead of the saints? 2Or do you not know that the saints will **judge** [G2919]  the world?

i.e., collective judgment according to Christ

> And if the world is to be judged [G2919] by you, are you incompetent to try trivial cases? 3 Do you not know that we are to **judge**  [G2919] angels?

i.e., collective judgment

> How much more, then, matters pertaining to this life!

Now, concerning lawsuits among believers:

> 4 So if you have such cases, why do you lay them before those who have no standing in the church? 5 I say this to your shame. Can it be that there is no one among you wise enough to settle a dispute between the brothers, 6but brother goes to law against brother, and that before unbelievers? 7To have lawsuits at all with one another is already a defeat for you. Why not rather suffer wrong? Why not rather be defrauded? 8 But you yourselves wrong and defraud—even your own brothers!

Believers should resolve conflicts among ourselves. In this sense, we G2919-judge.

Jesus also says that it is okay to G2919-judge with the condition in John 7:

> 24 Stop **judging**  [G2919] by mere appearances, but instead **judge** [G2919] correctly.

There is another Greek word for judging,
1 Corinthians 2:

> 15 The spiritual person **judges** [G350] all things, but is himself to be judged [G350] by no one.

G350 (judge, ἀνακρίνω, anakrinó) occurs 16 times.

HELPS Word-studies:

> 350 anakrínō (from 303 /aná, "up, completing a process," which intensifies 2919 /krínō, "to select by separating/judging") – properly, to distinguish by **vigorously** judging "down to up," i.e. closely **examining** (investigating) through "the process of careful study, evaluation and judgment" (L & N, 1, 27.44); "to examine, investigate, question (so J. B. Lightfoot, Notes, 181f).

In summary, do not condemn people. Don't be judgmental. When you do judge, judge as a mature spiritual believer carefully.

Comment: +1. The saying: "God loves the sinner, but hates the sin" is probably true. If so, we should copy God and judge acts and words, not the person behind these things. Thus, in a perfect world, the demons behind the bad stuff should be cast out of the sinners. Instead of condemning them to hell. Jesus and the women caught  in adultery comes to mind here.

Answer (score 3):

> I can of mine own self do nothing: as I hear, I judge: and my judgment is just; because I seek not mine own will, but the will of the Father which hath sent me [John 5:30 KJV]

The words of Jesus tell us how we should judge.

**Not of one's own self.**

> I am crucified with Christ: nevertheless I live; yet not I, but Christ liveth in me: and the life which I now live in the flesh I live by the faith of the Son of God, who loved me, and gave himself for me. [Galatians 2:20 KJV]

**Not of one's own legal opinion**

As I hear, I judge. That is to say as the voice of the Spirit is sensed. Thus to judge.

**Not of one's own will**

But according to the Father. Thy will be done on earth as it is in heaven.

---

Those who have repented and believed in Jesus Christ, who have thus been brought to the Father and are, as a result, led of the Spirit, may judge.

This is to judge righteous judgment.

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful and sage.  +1. But how then do we understand Matt 7:1, 2?

Answer (score 2):

One frequent cause of apparent contradictions is that words may have different meanings in different places. That is why we need to check the context to be sure that we know what the word is trying to say.

The short answer is that we are not allowed to judge people, but we are positively obliged to disecrn the difference between right and wrong, and sometimes this word "judge" is talking about discernment. That is, we are not allowed to tell an adulterer that he is evil, but we are allowed to declare that God disapproves of adultery.

All the quotations in your first list are about judging people, which is what we are not to do.

In the case of Luke ch12 v57, we can see from the followng verses that we are being asked to discern what is the right action for us to take as soon as possble. In other words, absolutely nothing to do with "judging others".

John ch7 v24 is about asking the Jews to recognise who Jesus is. "Right judgement" means "not judging him in a negative sense".

In Acts ch13 v26, Paul is complaining that they are (in effect) not regarding themselves as worthy to enter the kingdom. Again, he is not telling them to judge other people in a negative sense.

In 1 Corinthians ch5 v12, "judging within the church" is actually about discerning whether people's actions are helpful or unhelpful and trying to decide what needs to be done about the problem. That is what a judge in the legal system does (which is why there is nothing un-Christian about the work of a judge in the legal system).

In 1 Corinthians ch6, Paul is talking about a dispute between two parties which needs to be settled. Better within the community than in the civil courts Nothing to do with condemning either party as evil.

And the 1 Corinthians ch11 example is about discerning what is the right thing to do.

So the short answer is that we are allowed to judge when "judging" is just an alternative word for "discernment".

P.S. I think Tony Chan's answer appeared while I was in the middle of drafting mine. Any similarities are accidental.

Comment: +1 Good answer :)